# Laravel queue:work re-processing in every 60 seconds

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-queue

Using Laravel 5.4

PHP 7.0.10

QUEUE_DRIVER=database

using WampServer

I wanna send mail to a few user included 3MB or 6MB sized PDF attachment.
If i do not include PDF(s), everything works fine (probably in 10-20seconds)

If i include attachments, it probably takes above 60 seconds. 
So changed 'retry_after', but it doesn't not effect the queue.

in config/queue.php file:

```
    'database' => [
        'driver' => 'database',
        'table' => 'jobs',
        'queue' => 'default',
        'retry_after' => 600,
    ],
```

When i run artisan command:

```
php artisan queue:work --timeout=590
```

Queue worker restarts the process first in 30 seconds then in every 60 seconds

```
[2017-12-12 15:15:49] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:16:19] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:17:19] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:18:19] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:19:20] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:20:20] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:21:20] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
[2017-12-12 15:22:20] Processing: app\Jobs\SendMyEmail
```

I tried:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

And also tried:

```
php artisan queue:restart
```

Also tried to restart all wamp servers

BUT cannot solve the problem.

Comment: Check [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php).

Comment: Unfortunately not worked @Tpojka

Comment: Try to set value in `php.ini` file and restart server. `retry_after` is just when to try again. Problem here is execution period which is stored in set time limit imho.

Comment: @Tpojka in my php.ini file max_execution_time = 120 
But in my case (above) queue worker restarting process in every 60 seconds

Comment: Make a `Log::info("process started")` before and `Log::info("process finished")` after with any number of same line with appropriate message between. You can use it through if then else loop so you would know where is stuck. Like `if ( ! $someAction ) { Log::info("not some action"); }` Don't forget to include class at beginning `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;`. Then check in `storage/logs/laravel.log` what is written or where ever you have logs set. Before testing, delete everything from that file `cat /dev/null > storage/logs/laravel.log` on unix systems and if that is the name of file.

Comment: Also alway use `try catch` block and you will be able to know closely what is the error from `getMessage()` method in catch block.

Comment: Both PHP 7.0 and Windows are incompatible Laravel's automatic job timeouts. Your jobs are not timed outed for any value of timeout you specify. (However, a separate worker may still think that the job is up-for-grabs, but you're only running one worker so that isn't the issue.) Is any mails actually sent? Have you read your error logs? Perhaps this is just a 30/60 second timeout when attempting to connect to your mail server.